# Midpoint between two lines

Tags: geometry

I have that problem: "Given two secant lines $r,s$ in the plane and a point $P\notin r,s $, find a geometric method for obtain two points $R\in r, \; S\in s $ such that P is the midpoint of $RS$."

I know how to solve this problem analytically with the coordinates of $P$ and the equations of $r,s$, but I have nothing and I should use a geometric method, with "ruler and compass". 
Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the terminology "secant line".

Comment: I would say that the lines $r,s$ intersect in one point i.e. $r,s$ are not parallel

Comment: Just intersect $s$ with the symmetric of $r$ with respect to $P$ (or the opposite, $r$ with the symmetric of $s$ with respect to $P$).

Comment: By "secant" line did he mean a "skew" line ?

Comment: In some languages, the nomenclature for "intersecting lines" involves a word related to "secant."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the reflection $r'$ of line $r$ through point $P$. (This can be done by selecting any two points on $r$, constructing their reflections through $P$, and then drawing a line through the reflections.) The intersection of $r'$ and $s$ is the required point $S$. Then $R$ is obtained as the intersection of $PS$ and $r$.

This may, depending on how the construction is carried out, be the same answer as Futorologist's, but it gives a different interpretation of the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q = r \cap  s$.

1. Draw the line $QP$ and take point $T$ on $QP$ so that $QP = TP$ i.e. $P$ is the midpoint of $QT$;
2. Draw the lines $r'$ and $s'$ though point $T$ so that $r'$ is parallel to $r$ and $s'$ is parallel to $s$;
3. Let $R = r\cap s'$ and $S = s \cap r'$;

The segment $RS$ passes through $P$ and $P$ is its midpoint. The reason for that comes from the fact that by construction $QRTS$ is a parallelogram and as such, the diagonals $QT$ and $RS$ intersect at a common point which is a midpoint for both  $QT$ and $RS$. However, by construction, $P$ is the midpoint of $QT$ so $P$ should also lie on $RS$ and should be its midpoint.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Very clear answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]
It took me some time to draw the whole picture, so I'm a bit late regarding other answers, anyway here is my step by step solution.

I think credit should go to **@Jack D'aurizio** who was the quickest to give the hint.

Given lines $(r),(s)$, their intersection point $O$ and a point in the plan $P$ we can:

- trace line $(OP)$
- trace the circle $(\mathcal C)$ of center $P$ passing through $O$, it intersects $(OP)$ in $O\,'$ which is the symetrical of $O$ with respect to $P$.
- it also intersects $(r),(s)$ in respectively $A$ and $B$
- trace lines $(AP),(BP)$, they intersect $(\mathcal C)$ again in respectively $A\,'$ and $B\,'$ which are symetrical of $A,B$ with respect to $P$
- trace lines $(O\,'A\,')=(r\,')$ and $(O\,'B\,')=(s\,')$ which are symetrical of $(r),(s)$ which respect to $P$
- now $R=(r)\cap(s\,')$ and $S=(s)\cap(r\,')$ are the points requested in the question.

The fact the $P$ is middle of $[RS]$ is because by constructing $(r'),(s')$ we have built a parallelogram $(SORO\,')$ and their diagonals in blue $[OO\,']$ and $[RS]$ intersects in their middle.